# how to find total of two columns using php

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement, sum

[image: This is my excel data]

[image: This is mysql database]

The doubt is, whenever if issued field gets a value it should be added with previous balance value as in excel data. And whenever if receipt field gets a value it should be subtracted with previous balance value. Balance field should be updated by adding and subtracting issued and receipt values. How to do that in php.Can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.shop, A.IPOP, A.Item, A.Weight, A.Touch, A.issuedwt, A.receiptwt, 
       IF(A.IPOP = 'INPUT', @Balance:=@Balance + A.issuedwt, @Balance:=@Balance - A.receiptwt) AS Balance
FROM tableA A, (SELECT @Balance:=0) B
```

Comment: @user3060742 If you find your solution than You can upvote the answer by clicking on up arrow in the left of the answer and also accept the answer by clicking on true sign in the left of the answer. This will give say that you're active member of StackOverflow.

Comment: @user3060742 You can also take a tour of Stackoverflow for how to use. check the link http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

Select all records from database

```
select (issued + receipt) as balance from table
```

Gives you the sum of the two colums.

In your php script, keep a running total of all values as you loop through the resulting records. The exact logic of plusses and minus you will have to translate into code.

e.g.

```
if($row['receiptwt'] <> 0)
  {
  $balance = $balance-$row['receiptwt'];
  }
```